# Running Salesforce Code Analyzer for method version 3

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sobject, field-level-security

I'm trying to run the SalesForce Code Analyzer on the new version 3 to a unique method called deleteQuery and the deleteQuery has a parameter Id here what I'm using: "sfdx scanner:run:dfa --target./force-app/main/default/classes/accountController.cls#deleteQuery --projectdir ./force-app/main/default --outfile ./reports/thirdRun.csv --format=csv"

```java
@RemoteAction
    public static List<String> deleteQuery(String qId) {

        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsrListQuery = account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
        if (Schema.SObjectType.account.isDeletable() && Schema.SObjectType.account.isQueryable()) {
            account deletequery = new account(Id = qId);
            delete deletequery ;
            return new List<String>;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

but I'm receiving this message: "zsh: no matches found: ./force-app/main/default/classes/accountController.cls#deleteQuery", but the method exists.

Is it because the method has a parameter?

Comment: Have you tried to add simple quotes on the target path?

Comment: Yes, but when I tried to add simple quotes I got this message: 'zsh: no matches found: ‘./force-app/main/default/classes/accountController.cls#deleteQuery’'

Comment: hmm, have you tried to update the sfdx-cli?